# Active Model Serializer relations return only ids on production but full object on dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm having an issue with a discrepancy between what is happening on the live vs dev environment of my ruby on rails API.

On development I see the full object returned in the JSON result, however, on the production server we only get ids back.  I know about the `embed :ids, include: true` and I don't have that set so it's my understanding that the default behavior is to send the relation in as an object in the JSON so I'm not sure why it works that way on one environment and not the other.

I can't find anything in the active model serializers documentation about a global setting that might cause this.  Has anyone seen something like this or have any ideas what I could try?

DEVELOPMENT:

```
[
    {
        "zip": "84044",
        "city": "MAGNA",
        "state": "UT",
        "country": "USA",
        "rep": {
            "territory": "Utah, Montana & Wyoming",
            "type": "3form",
            "name": "Karey Spransy",
            "fname": "Karey",
            "lname": "Spransy",
            "sales_coordinator": {
                "id": 213536,
                "fname": "Misty",
                "lname": "Medina",
                "full_name": "Misty Medina",
            }
        },
        "studio_rep": {
            "territory": "Utah, Montana & Wyoming",
            "type": "3form",
            "name": "Karey Spransy",
            "fname": "Karey",
            "lname": "Spransy",
            "sales_coordinator": {
                "id": 213536,
                "fname": "Misty",
                "lname": "Medina",
                "full_name": "Misty Medina",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

PRODUCTION:

```
[
    {
        "zip": "90210",
        "city": "BEVERLY HILLS",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "USA",
        "rep_id": 284015,
        "studio_rep_id": 284693,
    }
]
```

Comment: You should share an [mcve] that reproduce your issue. I had a trouble similar and was able to solve it with the last version of active_model_serializer (0.10.6). I (or someone else) may be able to help you or other facing the same issue if you improve your question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for anyone that comes across this, we found that the issue was with upgrading the gem 'active_model_serializers' to the latest version. 0.10.x.  In our Gemfile we added a version to the active model serializers so that it would stay at version 0.8.3.  So our Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.3'
```

I know that this doesn't solve the problem with the newest version, but in researching this further I think the newest version wants you to use the json api adapter to generate it.

In our case we will eventually have to do that, but for now we will stick with the older version.